# Coldfusion session vars, via IFrame, via Ajax call

Tags: ajax, session, iframe, coldfusion, cross-domain

So I have a Coldfusion site (domain_a), being pulled into another site (domain_b) on a separate server via an iFrame. 
I have got it displaying, the Cross-Domain stuff has all been done and the index page displays within the iFrame with no issues.

Within my index page (domain_a), I am doing a few Jquery Ajax calls (simple .load() stuff) to pull in and populate a few elements. Within the index, and the scripts being requested, I am using session variables.

On my first page(index.cfm) my session is created (lets say CFID 1234). When I do my ajax call hits, I get a separate session returned (say CFID 2345). So my session is not persisting across separate requests.

This only happens in Safari and Firefox, Chrome is fine. I assume this must be something to do with Cross Domain rules.

Any ideas, either for how to keep each request mindful of the single session being used, or a better method than iFrame, or an alternative to using the session?